# Filter data in kendo dropdownlist

Tags: linq, kendo-ui

I want to ask you a question about filtering data from 2 dropdownlist.

First, I have a dropdownlist that contains 2 types of Persons "Phisic" and "natural" and another one that contains the gender of person "Unknown","female", "male".
If I select "Natural" values the other dropdownlist I wanna show just 2 genders "male" and "female".
How can I do this with linq and kendoUi() dropdownlist

Here is my code

```js
              
The controller that takes the gendertypes:

 vm.GenderTypes = _commonService.GetLocalizedDictionaryItems(DictionaryCodes.GenderType).ToList();

public static IQueryable<NamedItem> GetLocalizedDictionaryItems(this CommonService service, string dictionaryCode, params string[] itemCodes)
  {
   var q = service.GetDictionaryItems(dictionaryCode);
   if( itemCodes.Length > 0 )
    q = q.Where(a => itemCodes.Contains(a.Code));

   return (from a in q
     let name = GetCurrentLanguageField(a.NameAB, a.NameEN, a.NameSB)
     orderby name
     select new NamedItem()
     {
      Id = a.Id,
      Name = name
     }).UnwrapLocalizedQuery();
  }
```

```html
This code is for gender types 
@if( Model.CanSave )
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.GenderId)
                    .BindTo(Model.GenderTypes)
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    )
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Model.IsNatural){
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
                        <span class="readonly">@Html.DisplayDashFor(m => m.GenderName)</span>
                    }
                }



This code is for types of person;

 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsNatural)
                @if( Model.CanSave )
                {
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.PersonTypeCode)
                    .BindTo(new[] { new { Id = "natural", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Natural }, new { Id = "legal", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Legal } })
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    )
                }
                else
                {
                    <span class="readonly">@(Model.IsNatural ? Resx.PersonDetails.Natural : Resx.PersonDetails.Legal)</span>
  }
```

Comment: That's not hard, you can achieve that by using [cascading dropdownlists](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist). Could you post your code where you get the person types and genders?

Comment: @if( Model.CanSave )
                {
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
                    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.GenderId)
                    .BindTo(Model.GenderTypes)
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    )
                }
                else
                {
                    if(Model.IsNatural){
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GenderId)
                        <span class="readonly">@Html.DisplayDashFor(m => m.GenderName)</span>
                    }

Comment: For better readability, edit your question and post the code you inserted in your comment in it, if possible within a code block so people can read it. In a comment it's hardly readable. Also, post some controller code too

Comment: And for physic ad natural is :                                   @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.PersonTypeCode)
                    .BindTo(new[] { new { Id = "natural", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Natural }, new { Id = "legal", Name = Resx.PersonDetails.Legal } })
                    .DataTextField("Name")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    )
                }
                else
                {
                    <span class="readonly">@(Model.IsNatural ? Resx.PersonDetails.Natural : Resx.PersonDetails.Legal)</span>
                }

Comment: edit your question with your code..

Comment: any help?  would appreciate that